# Deligne tensor product of semisimple tensor categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, symmetric-monoidal-categories

Let $T_1, T_2$ be two **semisimple** tensor categories over a field $k$ (i.e. symmetric rigid monoidal abelian $k$-linear). Then is the Deligne product, $T_1\otimes T_2$ also a $k$-tensor category?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is. In the semi-simple case Deligne product is very explicit, see for example [BaKi](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~kirillov/tensor/tensor.html) Definition 1.1.15